# Asp.Net MVC 4, C# Entity FrameWork

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I created a two tables that is

1.SaleTable

```
public class Sales
{
    //[Key]
    //[ForeignKey("Stock")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StockId { get; set; }
    public int ReserveStockId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string ProductsName { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal SalePrice { get; set; }

    public virtual Stock Stock { get; set; }

}
```

2.Stock Table

public class Stock
    {

```
    public int StockId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal CostPrice { get; set; }

    //foriegn keys for product and expiredate
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ExpireDateID { get; set; }

    //association for product and expiredate table
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual ExpireDate ExpireDate { get; set; }

}
```

Im trying to write a code using MVC 4, in Visual Studio, and Entity Framework that will allow the following process to take place

1. When a user make sales, and he/she enter the sales records into the sales table,
2. The program will track the Quantity property of Goods/Products sold (from the Sales rec product) and deduct it from the Quantity property in the Stock Table

i.e for exameple, assume in a shop, there are 15 cups (in stock as recorded in the Stock Table, and 5 cups were sold, when the user enter the quantity and price of the cups sold, the program will track the quantity from the Sales Table and deduct it from the Stock table so that 10 cups will be left as records in the Stock table

Comment: Tell us what your specific question is.  It's important for a post to be clear about what you're asking.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make the title something meaningful. MVC-4 is a tag, and Visual Studio is the name of an IDE (not a language). Your question title should be something that explains the problem you're having and that will have meaning to people when it turns up in a search result. Use tags to classify, and the title to describe the issue or ask a question related to it. While you're at it, you should also make it more clear what **specific issue** you're asking us to help you solve; there is no question here. Thanks.